# scan character in do while loop java language

Tags: java, loops, char, do-while

Using a do…while() loop, scan for characters (one per line) and print. Loop terminator would be if the input is a vowel or if the number of inputted characters has already reached 5.

It's a simple problem but I don't know why it shows this:

Input:

```
  c
  f
  a
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

This is the code that I tried:

```
 int count = 0;
    char ch;

    do {
        ch = input.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(ch);
        count++;
    } while((ch != 'a') || (ch != 'e') || (ch != 'i') || (ch != 'o') || (ch != 'u') || (count < 5));
```

Comment: Your or-condition of the do-while-loop will always be true. Imagine that the character is 'a'. Then your statement reduces to (true) || (false)... Therefore it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix two things:

1. Increment `count` at each iteration.
2. The condition in the `while-loop` should check whether to continue to the next iteration or terminate, this is why we need to check if the character is not any of the vowels AND `count` is still less than 5.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 0;
char ch;
do {
    ch = input.next().charAt(0);
    count++;
    System.out.println(ch + " " + count);
} while((ch != 'a') && (ch != 'e') && (ch != 'i') && (ch != 'o') && (ch != 'u') && (count < 5));
```

Comment: It would be best if you could explain why you made the decisions that you did.

Comment: @NomadMaker good point, I added more clarifications